# Access data vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database where users updates info and get their count shown after every save. But when I done a split database the users are able to see total users count instead of individual count can some one help

Comment: You would have to store the users ID when they make an update, and then only count the records whose ID matches the current users.

Comment: So where do I do that can you help

Comment: To be honest this question is a bit too broad for here, the basic steps would be something like 1. You need to identify the user. 2. you need to add that user ID as field in your update records. 3. You need to use that current user ID as criteria in your count.  Break down your task into these steps and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused with this shall I send u the file is it possible for u to correct the file and send it

Comment: No sorry this is not a code writing service, and some of this is basic design.